# How to solve $sin(x) = n$ for all $n\in{\mathbb{R}}$?

Tags: trigonometry, eulers-number-e

I was wondering how one would solve the equation $sin(x) = n$ for all real $n$.
You could of course use the Taylor series of $sin^{-1}(x)$ but that wouldn't give an exact result.

So I thought maybe you can use Euler's formula for $sin(x)$ ($sin(x) = \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$) to get an exact result? Simplifying a little bit gives you $e^{ix} - e^{-ix} = z$ but I don't know how to solve that equation.

There has to be a way to get an exact result since using Python's SymPy module gives one (and WolframAlpha does so, too, I think).

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, it is impossible. Please read about transcendental functions.

Comment: What do you mean by *exact result*? For example, I assume $\arcsin n$ (plus integer multiples of $2\pi$ if you want all of the real number values) is not what you want. Are rational powers of rational numbers allowed? (Note that if either or both occurrences of "rational" is replaced with "real", then every positive real number can be represented.) If so, then presumably any finite sum of such numbers is also allowed. Anything else allowed? Incidentally, this assume that you're solving for specific numbers, but similar issues arise if you want to solve for a "closed form algebraic expression".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the equation $e^{ix} - e^{-ix} = z$ you can define $w=e^{ix}$, which gives
$$
w-\frac1w=z\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad w^2-zw-1=0.
$$
Therefore,
$$
w=\frac{z\pm\sqrt{z^2+4}}{2}
$$
and you can recover $x=-i\log w$. You need to be careful here since there are in fact may solutions, namely
$$
x=-i\log w=-i\log|w|+i(\arg w+2k\pi)
$$
with $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: The question would suggest the person may not know why there are multiple solutions. This is explained by Riemann Surfaces. I find it quite troublesome those are usually not mentioned in introductions to complex numbers.

Comment: @ArturWiadrowski I completely agree with you. Indeed the question seems to be asking for something of simple nature and thus why I avoided mentioning for example Riemann Surfaces. I hope that the complex logarithm is within the scope.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted. I'm sorry my question wasn't really clear